# Spring integration send List to MongoDB outbound channel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to poll data from MongoDB, process the data, while it is being processed, I must update that status of the data in DB as "PROCESSED" using MongoDB outbound channel.

When I query the MongoDB using the inbound channel, I get a list of Objects.

I use a transformer which traverses this list and updates the status as "PROCESSING".

When I pass this updated list, wrapped as payload, to the outbound MongoDB channel, hoping it would update status if all the elements in the DB, I get an exception.

> BasicDBObject can not be cast to BasicDBList

how to proceed here?

Answer (score 0):

You know, sounds like a bug in the Spring Data MongoDB.
We have there a code like in the `MongoTemplate.toDocument()`:

```
 if (!(objectToSave instanceof String)) {
        Document dbDoc = new Document();
        writer.write(objectToSave, dbDoc);
```

And after that we jump to the `MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal()`:

```
    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(entityType)) {
        writeCollectionInternal((Collection<?>) obj, ClassTypeInformation.LIST, (BasicDBList) bson);
        return;
    }
```

Where we indeed can't cast to the `BasicDBList` because our original `bson` is just that `Document`.

You can consider to use `Splitter` before modifying each entity and storing them into DB back individually, not as a list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using a Splitter is indeed what I am doing for now. But I think it would be a good feature to allow outbound channel to store a list of objects all at once rather than sending each object separately

Comment: Well, that is exactly what `MongoDbStoringMessageHandler` tries to do, but Spring Data MongoDB has that mentioned bug. I've notified SD team on the matter, so let's see what they will answer! Maybe already tomorrow...